# logger print null but echo print message in mule flow

Tags: mule, esb

I am iterating xml in foreach. Echo is printing correct message but logger is print null.

```
<foreach collection="#[xpath('//xmlsoap/soap/soapenv:Envelope')]"
            doc:name="For Each">
            <echo-component />
            <logger level="INFO" category="ProTSP Logger" message="#[payload]"
            doc:name="Logger" />
        </foreach>
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tested by removing echo ( Keep Logger alone) Or After For each, keep logger and observe the payload?.

Comment: yes, printing alone logger also print same

Comment: try with :- `#[message.payload]` instead of `#[payload]`

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem using dom to xml transformer.

```
<foreach collection="#[xpath('//xmlsoap/soap/soapenv:Envelope')]"
            doc:name="For Each">

            <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>
            <mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer doc:name="DOM to XML"/>



            <logger level="INFO" category="ProTSP Logger" message="#[payload]"
                doc:name="Logger" />
        </foreach>
```

Comment: So its fair to say that the logger was not "printing null" it was invoking the toString() for the dom class (what ever it is)